# Re-sharding not affected properly in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I had a sharded collection in MongoDB with 100 documents split across two shards in the ratio 100:0 i.e. 100 documents in shard 1 and 0 documents in shard 2. I performed a sh.splitAt() like this

```
mongos> sh.splitAt("test.col", {AGE:50})
{
"ok" : 1,
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1594623118, 1),
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1594623125, 4),
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
    }
 }
}
```

This was done in the view of splitting the documents in the ratio 50:50 i.e. 50 documents in shard 1 and 50 in shard 2. When I run a sh.status() command it shows the following

```
mongos > sh.status()
....other data
 test.col
                    shard key: { "AGE" : 1 }
                    unique: false
                    balancing: true
                    chunks:
                            s0  1
                            s1  1
                    { "AGE" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "AGE" : 50 } on : shard1 Timestamp(3, 0)
                    { "AGE" : 50 } -->> { "AGE" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard2 Timestamp(3, 1)
```

So by this it is seen that 1 to 50 is in shard1 and from 50 it is in shard 2. But when I check the getShardedDistribution() it shows no documents in shard 1.

```
 mongos > db.col.getShardDistribution()
 Shard s0 at s0/localhost:37017,localhost:37018,localhost:37019
 data : 0B docs : 0 chunks : 1
 estimated data per chunk : 0B
 estimated docs per chunk : 0

Shard s1 at s1/localhost:47017,localhost:47018,localhost:47019
 data : 5KiB docs : 100 chunks : 1
 estimated data per chunk : 5KiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 100

Totals
 data : 5KiB docs : 100 chunks : 2
 Shard s0 contains 0% data, 0% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 0B
 Shard s1 contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 53B
```

Why is this not re-sharded properly? What am I missing here ? Can someone help me out

Comment: Is the balancer running and what is its status?

Comment: sh.getBalancerState()
is returning true

Comment: You refreshed metadata on the router right?